XMLGET in snowflake is producing nulls when the data is correct
I have this query here in snowflake and its ouput
SELECT
    t.id AS transcript_id,
    section.value::string AS section,
    XMLGET(section.value, '$')::string AS section_content
FROM FACTSET_OPEN_ACCESS__RD.TRANSCRIPTS.TRANSCRIPTS_OPEN t,
    LATERAL FLATTEN(input => XMLGET(t.raw_xml, 'body'), path => 'section') section
WHERE t.id = 2676505;





TRANSCRIPT_ID
SECTION
SECTION_CONTENT




2676505
0
NULL


2676505
1
NULL



I know for sure the xml is correct and the table is correct and yet the xml content for section is producing NULL.
here is a short bit of my xml (its massive)


<body><section name="MANAGEMENT DISCUSSION SECTION"><speaker id="0"><plist><p>Welcome to the Imago BioSciences Virtual Investor Event. At this time, all participants are in a listen-only-mode. Following management's prepared remarks, we will hold a Q&amp;A session. To ensure that we have ample time to address everyone's questions during the Q&amp;A session,




Hi - please update your question with a valid XML string that illustrates the behaviour you are seeing and also show what you expect your SQL to return, using that XML string

Thanks for providing a little sample of the XML, but we can't reproduce this or find a solution if we can't reproduce. If you can't share data to reproduce, then contact support directly and give them a query id.
